# Nuxt 3, In server/api, How can I know whether api post method is GET of POST

Tags: nuxtjs3

I created a file in `/server/api/test.ts`.
When a request is made to this file, regardless of whether the method is get or post, I want to automatically put the value into "req" valuable.

What I tried is "event.context.method". This returns undefined.

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    let req = null
    
    if (event.context.method == 'get'){ // event.context.method return undefined!
        req = getQuery(event)
    } else{
        req = await readBody(event)
    }
    console.log( "▼ req ▼", req );
    ...
}
```

Comment: How do you call it? What is not working? I don't think that you even need to precise the wished method here since your file is not called `test.get.ts` or `test.post.ts`. https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/server#usage-examples

Comment: Oh, sorry! For that, I guess that axios/fetch have that somewhere in their headers? Not sure myself but you can probably find that one by inspecting the received object. Use a ```<pre>``` tag or a `console.log` to check the object in whole.

Comment: I just want to know how can I know the method is get or post in nuxt3>server api. "event.context.method" is not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below.

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  let req = null

  if (event.req.method === 'GET') {
      req = getQuery(event)
  } else {
      req = await readBody(event)
  }
  console.log("▼ method ▼", event.req.method);
  console.log("▼ req ▼", req);
})
```